# TypeError: sourceMaps.get is not a function in Vue 3, Jest, Vue-test-utils and Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs, vuejs3, ts-jest

I have a project with Vue 3, Typescript, Jest, babel and Vue-test-utils/next.
I recently tried to make that combination work, but all Tests that have some kind of function, fail because of this Error:

```
 tests/unit/example.test.ts
  HelloWorld.vue
    ✕ renders props.msg when passed (3ms)

  ● HelloWorld.vue › renders props.msg when passed

    TypeError: sourceMaps.get is not a function

      1 | describe("Can Jest test basic fucntions?", () => {
      2 |   it("should not fail to execute console.log", () => {
    > 3 |     console.log("test");
        |             ^
      4 |   });
      5 | });
      6 | /* 

      at _default (node_modules/@jest/source-map/build/getCallsite.js:89:20)
      at Function.write (node_modules/@jest/console/build/BufferedConsole.js:104:51)
      at CustomConsole._log (node_modules/@jest/console/build/CustomConsole.js:100:12)
      at CustomConsole.log (node_modules/@jest/console/build/CustomConsole.js:183:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/example.test.ts:3:13)
```

Googeling the Error Message didn't get me very far.

So my basic question is: How do I make a Vue 3 Project using Typescript work with jest and Vue-test-utils?

My current Setups is the following:

testfile:

```
describe("Can Jest test basic fucntions?", () => {
  it("should not fail to execute console.log", () => {
    console.log("test");
  });
});
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:unit:coverage": "vue-cli-service test:unit --verbose --coverage",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vuex-orm/core": "^0.36.4",
    "@vuex-orm/plugin-axios": "^0.9.4",
    "@vuex-orm/plugin-search": "^0.24.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.7",
    "vue-loader": "^16.5.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.11",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@intlify/vue-i18n-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.12",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.38.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "~2.1.3",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

vue.config.json:

```
/* eslint-disable */
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  assetsDir: "r",
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: "en",
      fallbackLocale: "en",
      localeDir: "translations",
      enableLegacy: false,
      runtimeOnly: false,
      compositionOnly: false,
      fullInstall: true,
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      },
    },
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "@/assets/scss/sd-main-colors.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.performance.maxEntrypointSize(400000).maxAssetSize(400000);
  },
};
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel",

  maxWorkers: "90%",

  verbose: true,
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "json", "vue"],
  transform: {
    // process `*.vue` files with `vue-jest`
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
  },
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{js,jsx, ts, vue}",
    "!**/node_modules/**",
    "!**/vendor/**",
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  testMatch: ["<rootDir>/**/*.test.ts"],
};
```

babel.config.json

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript", "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
};
```

I have added deleted, downgraded, upgraded and configured quite a lot.
I simply dont know which package is actually causing this Error, except I do suspect it is ts-jest.
ts-jest for example, warns me not to use typescript >4.0.0 so I downgraded it to the version you can see in the package.json.

I also created the app with vue-cli, so I used commands like

vue add typescript,

vue add unit-jest

etc.

I also had a variety of other problems like not accepting imports, not accepting ts Code in jest files, babel-jest beeing expected etc.

But the scope of the question now is this Error. I think that should be last thing not working in my configuration.